# php ajax call function every minute

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am developing a project where users can chat instantly (live chat) . In this chat message system to load data dynamically , i am using ajax call with setinterval method

> setInterval(function() {foo();}, 10000);

And also its working fine . it fetch the records and display correctly. For now its in development mode so no problem of calling the DB continuously but if its go live and  so many users added then using setinterval and calling the DB is affected the memory storage or the Sql dumped off or anyother problem arrise..

can anyone give idea of if am using and going in a right way or need to use anyother alternate method.

Comment: Have you thought of using push technology or use socket.io technology together with nodejs? An example project demo is found at [this link](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/03/nodejs-private-webchat/)

Comment: It's better to push than to poll (long poll, which is what you're doing here.)

Comment: For PHP socket library "Ratchet WebSockets for PHP" http://socketo.me is good to look for live chat applications

Comment: If its an instant chat app you probably want the interval to be less than 10 seconds!